# How can I make my recursive function go back to continue recursing other cells

Tags: python, recursion, pygame

I am making a word finder using Pygame.
The program loops through each cell in a grid,
on each cell, it runs a recursive function on it to see if
it belong in a series of cells to form a word.

So far my program works only half way. Say the grid looks like this:

[image]

My program will print `FOUND` three times, so it seems fine. 
But if the grid looks like this:

[image]

It will only print `FOUND` once. The reason is because once the program finds an adjacent cell that can carry on the series of cells,
it ditches other possibilties adjacent to that cell.

How can I make the program go back to the other adjacent cells after the recursion completes one of them?

Here is how I defined my recursive function:

```
    def adj(self, cell, idx, lst, wrd):
        x, y = self.cells.index(cell) // self.rows, self.cells.index(cell) % self.rows
        y1 = x - 1 if x else 0
        y2 = self.rows + 2 if x > self.rows + 2 else x + 2
        x1 = y - 1 if y else 0
        x2 = self.cols + 2 if y > self.cols + 2 else y + 2
        adjs = [cell for row in self.grid[y1:y2] for cell in row[x1:x2] if cell != self.grid[x][y]]
        for cell in adjs:
            if len(wrd) > idx:
                if cell.text == wrd[idx]:
                    idx += 1
                    lst.append(cell)
                    self.adj(cell, idx, lst, wrd)
```

And here is how I called it:

```
                for cell in grid.cells:
                    lst = [cell]
                    grid.adj(cell, 1, lst, word)
                    if ''.join([c.text for c in lst]) == word:
                        print("FOUND")
```

My code:

```
import pygame
pygame.font.init()

wn = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))


class Cell():
    def __init__(self, x, y, s, color=(0, 0, 0)):
        self.input_box = pygame.Rect(x, y, s, s)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.s = s
        self.color_inactive = color
        self.color_active = pygame.Color('purple')
        self.color = self.color_inactive
        self.text = ' '
        self.active = False
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, s)

    def check_status(self, pos):
        if self.input_box.collidepoint(pos):
            self.active = not self.active
        else:
            self.active = False
        self.color = self.color_active if self.active else self.color_inactive

    def type(self, char):
        if self.active:
            if char and char.lower() in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ':
                self.text = char

    def draw(self):
        txt = self.font.render(self.text, True, self.color)
        x, y = self.x+(self.s-txt.get_width())//2, self.y+(self.s-txt.get_height())*5//7
        wn.blit(txt, (x, y))
        pygame.draw.rect(wn, self.color, self.input_box, 2)


class Grid():
    def __init__(self, x, y, cols, rows, size, color=(0, 0, 0)):
        self.grid = [[Cell(i*size+x, j*size+y, size) for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
        self.cells = [cell for row in self.grid for cell in row]
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols

    def check_status(self, pos):
        for cell in self.cells:
            cell.check_status(pos)

    def type(self, char):
        for cell in self.cells:
            cell.type(char)

    def adj(self, cell, idx, lst, wrd):
        x, y = self.cells.index(cell) // self.rows, self.cells.index(cell) % self.rows
        y1 = x - 1 if x else 0
        y2 = self.rows + 2 if x > self.rows + 2 else x + 2
        x1 = y - 1 if y else 0
        x2 = self.cols + 2 if y > self.cols + 2 else y + 2
        adjs = [cell for row in self.grid[y1:y2] for cell in row[x1:x2] if cell != self.grid[x][y]]
        for cell in adjs:
            if len(wrd) > idx:
                if cell.text == wrd[idx]:
                    idx += 1
                    lst.append(cell)
                    self.adj(cell, idx, lst, wrd)


    def draw(self):
        for cell in self.cells:
            cell.draw()


grid = Grid(50, 50, 10, 10, 32)
word = 'CAT'

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            grid.check_status(event.pos)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            grid.type(event.unicode)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                for cell in grid.cells:
                    lst = [cell]
                    grid.adj(cell, 1, lst, word)
                    if ''.join([c.text for c in lst]) == word:
                        print("FOUND")

                        
    wn.fill((255, 255, 200))
    grid.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is you only have one list. If you want to find more than one word you need a list of lists:

```py
if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
    for cell in grid.cells:
        lstlst = [[cell]]
        grid.adj(cell, 1, lstlst, word)
        for lst in lstlst:
            if ''.join([c.text for c in lst]) == word:
                print("FOUND")
```

When a new character is identified, you need to copy the last list of the list of lists:

```py
taillst = lstlst[-1]
```

```py
lst = taillst[:]
```

Append the new cell to the copy and add the copy to the end of the list of lists:

```py
lst.append(cell)
lstlst.append(lst)
```

Do not increment `idx`,  but pass `idx + 1` to the next recursion level:

```py
self.adj(cell, idx+1, lstlst, wrd)
```

Complete method `adj`:

```py
class Grid():
    # [...]

    def adj(self, cell, idx, lstlst, wrd):
        x, y = self.cells.index(cell) // self.rows, self.cells.index(cell) % self.rows
        y1 = x - 1 if x else 0
        y2 = self.rows + 2 if x > self.rows + 2 else x + 2
        x1 = y - 1 if y else 0
        x2 = self.cols + 2 if y > self.cols + 2 else y + 2
        adjs = [cell for row in self.grid[y1:y2] for cell in row[x1:x2] if cell != self.grid[x][y]]
        taillst = lstlst[-1]
        for cell in adjs:
            if len(wrd) > idx:
                if cell.text == wrd[idx]:
                    lst = taillst[:]
                    lst.append(cell)
                    lstlst.append(lst)
                    self.adj(cell, idx+1, lstlst, wrd)
```

The following pattern

[image]

returns the following 6 lists with 3 matches:

```py
['C']
['C', 'A']
['C', 'A', 'T']
['C', 'A', 'T']
['C', 'A']
['C', 'A', 'T']
```